# How to access nested data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a datasnapshot on the start of an activity. And i would like to loop through this data but i dont know how to access the nested array inside my child.

[Firebase data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbxKp.png)

This is the code i got at the moment to retrieve the name. I would also like to retrieve the latLng.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep using `child()` to dig into the nested data, which are also going to show up as DataSnapshot objects:

```
ds.child("latLng").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
ds.child("latLng").child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
```